# MS Sql sever 2005 installation error

Tags: sql-server-2005

When trying to install sql server 2005 on Windows 2003 server ,i am getting the error 
'Failed to load SqlCu.dll'

I've tried searching elsewhere but not found and solutions to the error. Any ideas much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

May be due to corrupted installation media.